# Toast Message is not displayed?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to give an application, Bluetooth connectivity when the Bluetooth is turned on it does not show the toast message

```
if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    Toast.makeText(HeartRate.this, "Turned on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
```

Comment: you forgot to call `show()`: `Toast.makeText(HeartRate.this, "Turned on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Pro tip: When creating toasts in Android Studio, you can type `toast` and Press **Tab** on your keyboard. It will automatically write the whole line for you, including `show()`, you simply need to edit the message

Comment: I just tried and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot something

```
 if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
//.show happens a lot of times to me
                Toast.makeText(HeartRate.this, "Turned on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```